# Converting a vertical tree into a horizontal tree in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I want to draw the following tree using tikz.
[image]

But I have already drawn the tree in vertical format.
[image]

Is there any way to convert the above diagram horizontally?

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage{times}%times new roman
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} %% for drwaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaing special symbols
\usepackage{empheq} %for box outside the equations
%%%%% Script for griffiths
% \usepackage{calligra}
% \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalligra}{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}
% \DeclareFontShape{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.2]callig15}{}
% \newcommand{\scripty}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathcalligra{#1}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%% script for griffths 2
\usepackage{calligra}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcalligra}{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{T1}{calligra}{m}{n}{<->s*[2.2]callig15}{}
\newcommand{\scriptr}{\mathcalligra{r}\,}
\newcommand{\boldscriptr}{\pmb{\mathcalligra{r}}\,}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes, arrows,arrows.meta,backgrounds,calc,decorations,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing,fit,positioning,shapes.arrows,shapes.callouts,shapes.geometric,shapes.misc}   
\usepackage{circuitikz} %for drwaing ee circuit
\usepackage [edges, linguistics]{forest} % for drawing forest

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
 [a
 [b][c[d][e]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `graphics` is already loaded by `graphicx`, so loading it additionally, does not make sense. `tikz` also loads `graphicx`. So loading `graphicx` before `tikz` is not needed. `circuittikz` also loads `tikz`. And package `times` is deprecated, see the [the manual of the package, that provides `times` only for backward compatibility](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/psnfss/psnfss2e.pdf).

Comment: @cabohah In the reverence mentioned by you, the labels are rotated

Comment: But this is not a necessary part of the answer. The important part of the answer is using `grow` and setting it using `for tree`. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use option `grow=east`. See the `forest` manual for more information about the option and how to set it for the node and all descendants using `for tree`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage [edges, linguistics]{forest} % for drawing forest

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={grow=east},
    forked edges
 [a
 [b][c[d][e]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: grow east forest]

Or using `grow'=east` to set `reverse` to `true` instead of `false`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage [edges, linguistics]{forest} % for drawing forest

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{forest}
    for tree={grow'=east},
    forked edges
 [a
 [b][c[d][e]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: There manual also explains a `grow''`, that does not change `reverse`. In the example it would show the same result as `grow`.

Comment: The diagram drawn by you is vertically opposite in order.

Comment: @darkphysics Sorry. And please read the manual.